# Hartshorne Proposition II.6.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

The statement of part (a) of this proposition is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension 1. Let $Z$ be a proper closed subset of $X$, and let $U=X\setminus Z$. Then there is a surjective homomorphism $\mathrm{Cl}(X)\to\mathrm{Cl}(U)$ defined by $\sum n_i Y_i\mapsto\sum n_i(Y_i\cap U)$, ignoring empty intersections.

Now, this seems like it should be blatantly obvious, and the proof in the book more or less treats it as such. I'm having trouble with the first line:

> If $Y$ is a prime divisor on $X$, then $Y\cap U$ is either empty or a prime divisor on $U$.

Clearly the former possibility is trivial. For some reason, I'm having trouble with the latter. A prime divisor is defined to be a closed integral subscheme of codimension one. Now, obviously $Y\cap U$ is closed in $U$. But to refer to it as a closed subscheme, don't I need to know what the subscheme structure is? Earlier they refer to the induced reduced closed subscheme structure; I guess I'm supposed to assume this is what they mean, but I'm not 100% sure (though I don't know what else makes sense).

Moving past this for now, I need to know that $Y\cap U$ is integral in $U$ and that $\mathrm{codim}(Y\cap U,U)=1$. Maybe I'm just confusing myself here; since $Y$ is integral (it's a prime divisor on $X$) and $Y\cap U$ is open in $Y$, we know $Y\cap U$ is integral as a subscheme of $Y$; that is, $(Y\cap U, \mathcal{O}_Y|_{Y\cap U})$ is an integral scheme. But is this the same as the closed subscheme structure of $Y\cap U\subseteq U$? Does it even matter?

Finally, the codimension; $\mathrm{codim}(Y,X)=1$ means that there are no irreducible closed subsets of $X$ strictly between $Y$ and $X$ (both are integral, hence irreducible themselves). I think I can see at least why this is true. Assuming we know $Y\cap U$ is an integral (hence irreducible) closed subscheme of $U$, either its codimension is one or it equals $U$. But the latter would force $U\subseteq Y$, which would make $X=Y\cup Z$ not irreducible, which would be a contradiction.

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction here; am I way overthinking this? Or are there really some subtleties that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let X be a an integral scheme, Y a closed integral subscheme of codimension 1, and U a nonempty open subscheme.  With the topology induced from U,  $Y \cap U \subset U$ is closed, and with the reduced subscheme structure induced from U, it becomes a reduced subscheme of U.  With the topology induced from Y, $Y \cap U \subset Y$ is irreducible, as a nonempty open subset of an irreducible space.  Since Y and U induce the same topologies on $Y \cap U$, one sees that as a scheme $Y \cap U$ is integral (reduced and irreducible).

Now $\mathrm{codim}(Y \cap U, U) = \mathrm{codim}(Y, X) = 1$ follows from the fact that there is a bijection $Z \mapsto \overline{Z}$ from the set of closed irreducible subspaces of U to the set of closed irreducible subspaces of X intersecting U, which in fact maps irreducible components to irreducible components.  (See (EGA, 0_IV, 14.2.3).)

Comment: I've read about this reduced induced closed subscheme structure in Hartshorne (Exa II.3.2.6) but, despite the name, it does not seem to be proved to produce a reduced scheme. I think I've proved it when the parent scheme is affine; I assume it's still true for more general schemes, but the process with the gluing, etc., seems rather complicated. Is this the right approach?

I see that $Y\cap U$ is irreducible in $Y$ as you said; in the subspace topology, doesn't this depend on the parent space? I think I can prove it in this case anyway (see next comment), but I'd like verification of this.

Comment: Proof that $Y\cap U$ is irreducible (in $U$?): Suppose not; then $Y\cap U=Z_1\cup Z_2$, where $Z_i$ are closed in $U$ ($Z_i=Y\cap U\cap C_i$, where $C_i$ is closed in $U$. But then $Z_i=Y\cap U\cap C_i=Y\cap Y\cap U\cap C_i=(Y\cap U)\cap(Y\cap C_i)$. Since $Y\cap C_i$ is closed in $Y$, this would show that $Y\cap U$ is closed in the subspace topology induced by $U$. Is all this necessary, or is the result somehow trivial?

Comment: Yes, the result is trivial if you take the right definition of an irreducibile space, namely a non-empty topological space in which two non-empty  open subsets always heve non-empty intersection. It is then obvious that a non-empty open subset of an irreducible space is irreducible.

Comment: Dear Adeel, "irreducible" is an intrinsic concept, not a relative one. Once you know that $Y\cap U$  is irreducible (if  non empty: you should add that in your answer) by considering it as open in $Y$ (see my comment above) , you are done.

Comment: @Georges, irreducibility at least depends on the topology we put on the set of course.  Here we take $Y \cap U$ with the topology induced from U.  If we take it with the topology induced from Y then it is clearly irreducible.  But it is not obvious to me that irreducibility is independent of this choice.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Dear Adeel, *all* subsets under consideration have the topology induced from $X$. The point is that taking subset topology is transitive: if $S\subset T\subset X$, then the subset topology on $S$ inherited from $X$ is the same as the subset topology inherited from $T$, where $T$ has the subset topology inherited from $X$ (this is pure set-theoretic topology and has nothing to do with algebraic geometry).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, I see now.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Dear Adeel, you are welcome.

Comment: @topspin1617, as for the reduced induced subscheme structure, this really deserves a more more thorough treatment than the exercise in Hartshorne.  I would take a look at the relevant section in EGA I if possible, or the [Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3).

Comment: Alright... I think I mostly understand it now, from the answer and subsequent comments. Does anyone know of a place to read EGA, etc.? Was never able to get/view a copy from my school's library.

Comment: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php